# SQL Fiddle's "Text to DDL" option

Tags: sqlfiddle

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) has a very nice option to post table's content into its "Text to DDL" window so all `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements are automatically generated.

Is there a way to specify column names there **before** the result is applied to the left (DDL) window?

I can obviously copy the result out to my text editor, do file-wide replacements and copy it back, but prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names are the first row of your text input. If you have some text that doesn't seem to be working correctly, please submit a ticket on my sub-project specificly for this function: https://github.com/jakefeasel/DDLBuilder (of course include the failing text input in the ticket).

Comment: Ok I don't understand, clearly. "Other than character strings"? Does that mean character strings work differently than other types, somehow? The column names are simply the first row of text - if you want to change the name, you have to change the input text.